# Is the indicative "correct" when dealing with a conditional future?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct: “what if there was” or “what if there were”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/which-is-correct-what-if-there-was-or-what-if-there-were)

Someone recently [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121666/small-grammar-bug-on-area51) to meta.stackoverflow.com about a plural bug on Area 51, writing

> ...it doesn't effect [sic] the functionality of the site, but it'd be nice if the grammar was correct...

I jokingly pointed out that he meant *"It would be nice if the grammar **[were](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English)** correct."*

The user [Gilles](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1165/gilles) commented

> ...you picked something that's actually not an error... you don't have to use the subjunctive, the indicative is also correct.

That's not my understanding at all, but I've never *studied* grammar. We're dealing with a speculative/conditional future, the subjunctive is required, isn't it?

I recognize that language is a living thing, and that in English our use of the subjunctive is decreasing. But surely the indicative is not correct in this case? At least not yet?

Comment: In full application of Skitt's law, I shouldn't have called it an indicative, it is not an indicative. What I should have said is that while *were* is formally the “most correct” subjunctive form, *was* is perfectly standard usage. Also, I'm sure this has been asked hundreds of times here before.

Comment: @Gilles: LOL, I was wondering if we'd end up with an endless series of Skitt's Law examples. :-) I understand that using "was" here is common. But I wouldn't call it *correct*. (To give you an idea of my upbringing, my father's voice comes to me from across the years: "*'Common'* is ***exactly*** what it is." ;-) ) If you see a duplicate referring to the future conditional case, by all means flag it. I didn't, in a few minutes of looking, but that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I did flag a duplicate, one from the “related” column. I picked http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705; upon reflection “If I were” may be a special case, and maybe [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44706/was-or-were-in-subjunctive-clauses) is closer and not an exact duplicate. [Hmmm](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+was%2Cif+I+were%2Cif+it+was%2Cif+it+were%2Cif+he+was%2Cif+he+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* treats this *were* as an irrealis form of *be* and not the subjunctive, which is typically realized by the bare form of the verb (e.g., *important that you be on time*). It says the *were* version belongs to a formal style, but that the *was* version is standard.

Comment: Thanks. Which section / chapter / etc.?

Comment: But it *is* historically the subjunctive. It's just that in modern English, the subjunctive is used in two completely-looking different ways (this one and "it is necessary that he *be* detained"), and they think that using the same name for both  would be confusing. The irrealis *were* is slowly losing ground to the indicative, and is considered optional by  many grammarians.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Chapter 3, section 1.7