# "If something were" or "If something was" in the 2nd conditional?

Tags: british-english, subjunctive-mood, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct: “what if there was” or “what if there were”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/which-is-correct-what-if-there-was-or-what-if-there-were)
>   [Correct usage of was/were on the object of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/correct-usage-of-was-were-on-the-object-of-a-sentence)
>   [“Was” or “were” in subjunctive clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44706/was-or-were-in-subjunctive-clauses)

I have the following sentence in the draft of my latest paper:

> No arbitrage would be introduced if the project were traded.

Is this version correct? Or should it be:

> No arbitrage would be introduced if the project was traded.

What are the rules here?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, purists might prefer "were", but "was" should be fine.